# Не работает JS скрипт после редиректа

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, редирект

Имеется страница на OpenServer. На этой странице есть форма, после отправки которой выполняются некоторые манипуляции с базой данных. После этого происходит редирект обратно на страницу с формой и выполняется js скрипт.

```
<?php
...
echo <script> ... </script>
?>
```

Вот скрипт:

```js
"use strict";
window.location.replace('http://test/test.html');
alert("How are you doing, man?");
var label = document.getElementById("label");
label.style.color = 'red';
alert(label);
```

На той странице есть элемент с id = 'label', однако после редиректа выводится null во втором alert'е, даже если взять другой элемент. И, соответственно, цвет элемента не меняется. До редиректа все изменения проходят. Так в чем же дело?

Comment: У вас скрипт, показанный в вопросе, находится на той же странице где и элемент с id = 'label' или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте скрипт взять в событие onload страницы.

```
window.onload = function(){
    //// код
}
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: Тот же результат :(

Answer (score 1):

На какой "той странице"? Подозреваю, что имеется в виду страница `'http://test/test.html'`.

> Это не будет делать то.

Из Вашего скрипта Вы не получите доступ к элементам страницы, которая еще не загрузилась. А когда она загрузится, Вашего скрипта уже не будет.

Comment: И как сделать, чтоб работало?

Comment: @GeekBrain Никак.

Comment: Вот я теперь сделал скрипт внешним, и поставил ему defer. Но он все равно обрабатывается ДО загрузки страницы (test.html). Как сделать, чтобы сначала страница загрузилась, а потом сработал скрипт?

Comment: @GeekBrain Вставить скрипт в страницу.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся только после отправки формы. Как сделать на странице проверку, была ли отправлена форма?

Comment: @GeekBrain `<form onsubmit="yourFunction();" ...`